# php- popping a value from array returns wrong result

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, I will explain what I am trying to implement here. It's like a number search. I will pass a number and server returns an array of all number. If the passed number is present, I will have to pop that number from the array.

It works, but not in all scenarios.

```
<?php

function fetchAll()
{
    $data= array();
    $motherArray='["1","48","2","44","4"]';
    $data       =   json_decode($motherArray); 
    return $data;
}

$allIDs=fetchAll();
if (!empty($allIDs)) 
{
    $checkThis=4;
    if(in_array($checkThis,$allIDs))
    {
        if (($key = array_search($checkThis, $allIDs)) !== false) 
        {
            unset($allIDs[$key]);
        }       
        if(!empty($allIDs))
        {       
            $allIDsJSON         = json_encode($allIDs);
            echo $allIDsJSON;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'empty';
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not present';
    }
}

?>
```

Above given is my code. I'm trying to search for the number 4.

Number 4 can be in any position. It can be in first, middle or the last. My code works if the number is in last position. Then, it returns the correct output.

**Case 1**:

```
$motherArray='["1","48","2","44","4"]';
```

if it is in last position, I get the correct output:

```
["1","48","2","44"]
```

**Case 2**:

If number 4 is in any other position

$motherArray='["1","48","2","4","44"]';

then the output I get is:

```
{"0":"1","1":"48","2":"2","4":"44"}
```

I don't know why it is happening like that.
Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this code?

Comment: *If number 4 is in any other position* - array has not sequential indexes, and decode function create an object. Use `$allIDsJSON  = json_encode(array_values($allIDs));`

Comment: the above is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You're code won't work if there is multiple value of your number:

`foreach (array_keys($allIDs, $checkThis) as $key)
    unset($allIDs[$key]);`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is provided in the comments already.I will just add it here with some explanation.

If number is not in last position then when you `unset($allIDs[$key]);` you create an array that is not sequential.

Original array:
`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 48 [2] => 2 [3] => 4 [4] => 44 )`

Array after unsetting third element: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 48 [2] => 2 [4] => 44 )`

Because in javascript there are not associative arrays when you use  `json_encode($allIDs);` the valid JSON result you get is a JSON object not an array.

So if you want an array you have to reindex the array yourself like that:

```
$indexed_array = array();

foreach ($allIDs as $row) {
    $indexed_array[] = $row;
}

json_encode($indexed_array);
```

Or by using `array_values` function

```
echo json_encode(array_values($allIDs))
```

Comment: I used the answer provided in comments and it worked. He didn't add it as an answer, co i couldn't accept it, instead gave a vote